# MONTH() function, to search through entire column

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am currently trying to learn more about the MONTH function within excel.

Basically, I have a bunch of columns, and I want it to only find those which meet my criteria stated within a countifs function.

At the moment I have.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sorted!A:A, "HatType", Sorted!D:D, "PantType", Sorted!C:C, MONTH(TODAY()))
```

It is working for the first two criteria, however id also like to add a check for matching the month of the request.

However, it is returning with 0, despite 3 that should be matching. **Month(Today))** is returning 1 (for todays month),  I have tried putting the sorted for c column in like this, **Month(Sorted!C:C)**, but it isn't working.

Do you guys have any tips on how to get this working, without creating a new column to separate each dates months.

Comment: For better understanding please, share a good example of the data (headers, and data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use the [MONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) against an range in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff), you canot use it directly against a range in a [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) or [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) function. However, you **can** create a date window for the matching records and COUNTIFS is a vastly more efficient formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sorted!A:A, "HatType", Sorted!D:D, "PantType",
          Sorted!C:C, ">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1),
          Sorted!C:C, "<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1))

=SUMPRODUCT((Sorted!A:A="HatType")*(Sorted!D:D="PantType")*
            (MONTH(Sorted!C:C)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR(Sorted!C:C)=YEAR(TODAY())))
```

Caution: The [TODAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) is a volatile¹ function.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this has helped me very much.

In regards to expanding the countifs example, if I wanted to lets say, include dates from the beginning of the current month and the end of the next month, id simply replace the +1 on the < portion of the formula with a +2?

Comment: The **+2** sounds right; whatever method you can use to create the upper boundary of the date 'window'. Note that I used *'less than the first of the next month'*. This is because if I had used *'less than or equal to the last day of the month'* then datetimes on the last day of the month like  31-Jan-2016 01:30 PM would not be caught.

Comment: Given that the Today function updates the entire workbook, if I ever decide to scale this up, is there another function which does not update everything but applies a similar result?

Comment: Put (type) the date in a cell and reference that or use a VBA User Defined Function (aka UDF) that returns either **Date** or **Now**. VBA UDF functions are not volatile unless you tell them to be. You do not have the same choice with the native worksheet functions.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that mate. 

Would this also apply with a sumifs formula? I tried fooling around with one last night, but it was returning a #Value!.

Its exactly the same as your worked answer, just passing in the range of values that I want summed, within the sum range.

Comment: To change the above COUNTIFS to a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B), just insert the sum range as the first parameter and change COUNTIFS to SUMIFS. Note that all ranges have to be the same size.

Comment: Thanks again mate,

Am I able to utilize the same function idea to have this return dates only found within the current quarter? or half of year? I am just trying to think of more unique ways to capture sets of data.

Comment: I have tried converting this to utilizing datedif(), my only issue is I am finding it hard to reference an entire date column. The only way I can think of doing this, is to reference the column in the first range. and hard set the cut off date as the 2nd range.